# Binding List to GridView in ASP .Net C# MVC Jquery

Tags: c#

I have a list of credit card objects. The credit card class is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Client
{
    public class CreditCard
    {
        public String A_Number;
        public String A_Name;
        public String A_Type;
        public String A_Owner_Type;
        public String Bank_City;
        public String Bank_State;
        public String Bank_ZIP;
        public String Balance;
        public String C_Username;

        public CreditCard()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In another class, I am trying to bind the list to a grid view as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<CreditCard> list = (List<CreditCard>)Session["list"];
    GridView_List.DataSource = list;
    GridView_List.DataBind();
}
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

> The data source for GridView with id 'GridView_List' did not have any
>   properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that
>   your data source has content.

Answer (score 0):

You must use public properties for DataBinding. Update your class as follows:

```
public class CreditCard
    {
        public String A_Number { get; set; }
        public String A_Name { get; set; }
        public String A_Type { get; set; }
        public String A_Owner_Type { get; set; }
        public String Bank_City { get; set; }
        public String Bank_State { get; set; }
        public String Bank_ZIP { get; set; }
        public String Balance { get; set; }
        public String C_Username;

        public CreditCard() { }
    }
```

BeingSerach http://beingsearch.com